# how to unit test javascript client-side authentication

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, authentication, tdd

I'm trying to get better at unit testing (and hopefully teach myself TDD). My current project is in Javascript, which I'm new to. I was wondering how I can unit test my authentication? I imagine I'll probably have to make a mock server to substitute for the one I will actually be authenticating against, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

If testing framework matters at all to the answer, I've been trying to use JSTestDriver--though if it's easier with something else I'm open to learning since I don't have a whole lot of time invested into a particular framework yet.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the full system is a little too broad to answer here, but I can address the portion about using a mock server.

[Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/), a test-double library, has a fake XHR/server that's great for simulating responses.

In this example from the [docs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server), we initialize the fake server during setup and remove it in teardown. Then we tell the server what data to return using `server.respondWith()`.

The server call normally made by `getCommentsFor()` is intercepted by the fake server and fed the data we've provided in our test using `respondWith()`. By invoking `server.respond()`, the fake server call is executed immediately, meaning we don't have to account for a normally asynchronous operation.

```
{
    setUp: function () {
        this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    },

    tearDown: function () {
        this.server.restore();
    },

    "test should fetch comments from server" : function () {
        this.server.respondWith("GET", "/some/article/comments.json",
                                [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                                 '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]']);

        var callback = sinon.spy();
        myLib.getCommentsFor("/some/article", callback);
        this.server.respond();

        sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, [{ id: 12, comment: "Hey there" }]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! You're right that this may be too broad a topic for a single SO question, but you've given me a great starting point. Thank you so much for that because I've been struggling. I'll be reading up on Sinon.JS this weekend.